# Evaluating Series at a point not working

Tags: functions, warning-messages, complex, variable-definitions

I have a series as an output and I am trying to plot it and/or evaluate it. How come that doesn't work? I get:

> Attempt to evaluate a series at the number 0.10001838571428572`.
>   Returning Indeterminate.

```
IntegrandSerie[x, z] /. {Z0 -> 1, S[x] -> 1, dWNorm[x] -> 1, 
dWNorm1 -> 1, z -> 2}    

(*Output: Abs[-12. + (1.95833 + 7.7 I) beta + (1.40482 - 0.584549 I) 
beta^2+O[beta]^5/2]^2*)

Plot[IntegrandSerie[x, z] /. {Z0 -> 1, S[x] -> 1, dWNorm[x] -> 1, 
dWNorm1 -> 1, z -> 2}, {beta, 0.1, 1}]
```

If I then do:

```
N[Abs[-12. + (1.95833 + 7.7 I) beta + (1.40482 - 0.584549 I) 
beta^2]^2]/.beta->1
```

I actually get a value of 125.225. However, `Plot[N[...]]` doesn't work.

Comment: Please show a complete, reproducible example.  Make it minimal: remove everything from the question that is irrelevant. "Serie" is not a word, you probably meant "series".

Comment: What is `IntegrandSerie` or even `IntegrandSeries` - I cannot find any in the docs?

Comment: @gwr those were my own functions. I believed it was not relevant. Rather, the important thing is the output. That is why I am not showing the previous part. Am i wrong in doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the [`O`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/O.html) using `Normal`:

```
(* using your reported output *)
out =  Abs[-12. + (1.95833 + 7.7 I) beta + (1.40482 - 0.584549 I) beta^2 +O[beta]^5/2]^2;

Plot[ Evaluate @ Normal @ out, { beta, 0.1, 1 } ]
```

[image: Plot]

So maybe a simple `Evaluate` might help.

Update: Including the Bachmann-Landau notation of the OP's edited question.

Comment: I was wrong, I have updated the output received. The problem is that O[beta]. Can you see my problem now?

Comment: I got it. I am now wondering why we also need that Evaluate to let Normal work

Comment: I am a bit new to Mathematica. So, when I am satisfied with an answer shall I turn the tick green and click on the up arrow? Then, what other question are you saying? I cant find it :)

Comment: I am not sure if you are talking about this same post here, or by another question you mean another post completely. In any case, I can't find it back. From now on I will vote up when I am satisfied Could you now please explain me that thing about Evaluate and Normal?

Comment: @AndreaG Plot has the attrtibute `HoldAll` and in the details section of its documentation you will find that an `Evaluate` sometimes is needed. There are also lots of posts around on M.SE if you start looking...

Comment: I have another question at this point: if rather than evaluating IntegrandSerie and leaving it as a function of (x,z) I make a definite integral over say, (-1,1) and (-1/2,1/2) I automatically get ride of that O[beta]. How come? No need to use this Normal when Integrating?

Comment: ok thanks, what is M.SE short for?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the function you want to plot really a function of beta, like

```
 f[beta_?NumericQ]=IntegrandSerie[x, z] /. {Z0 -> 1, S[x] -> 1,dWNorm[x] -> 1, 
dWNorm1 -> 1, z -> 2}
```

and then plot

```
Plot[f[x],{x,0,.1,1}]
```